# Laravel 8 migration show "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

when running "php artisan migrate:fresh" command it shows  SQLSTATE[42000] error

Here is the full error message

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) def' at line 1 (SQL: create table `products` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null, `description` varchar(1000) not null, `quantity` int unsigned not null, `status` varchar(191) not null default 'unavailable', `image` varchar(191) not null default 'unavailable', `seller_id` varchar(191) unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

and here is the migration
Product::UNAVAILABLE_PRODUCT is defined in Product model as 'unavailabel'

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description',1000);
            $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
            $table->string('status',)->default(Product::UNAVAILABLE_PRODUCT);
            $table->string('image',)->default(Product::UNAVAILABLE_PRODUCT);
            $table->string('seller_id',)->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('seller_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
        $table->string('seller_id',)->unsigned();
```

There's no such thing as an unsigned string. Either remove the `unsigned()` option for this column, or else define it as an integer.

Comment: Yes, my copy-paste mistake.